# BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'get_text' sometimes in the same code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

Does anyone know where this problem comes from? I run the same code in a few seconds and sometimes it gives me that error and sometimes [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2bha.png) it doesn't.

```
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), 'html.parser')
title = soup2.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
price = soup2.find(class_='aok-offscreen').get_text()

print(title)
print(price)
```

It really is the same code and I run it and sometimes it shows an error, [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJQKi.png) I continue searching for elements and working one yes and one no, thank you.

```
---> 10 title = soup2.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
     11 price = soup2.find(class_='aok-offscreen').get_text()
     14 print(title)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there isn't an element that have the id "productTitle". You can try running it on two sperate commands like

```
title_elem = soup2.find(id='productTitle')
print(title_elem)
```

This will print None. So when you try to access get_text() method on title_elem like

```
print(title_elem.get_text())
```

This will generate an error.

Comment: If I run it once it gives me an error, the next time it doesn't give me an error, the next time it gives me an error, it's like a random error, when it wants it runs, I don't know if you saw the images, one gives an error and the other doesn't, with the same code, anyway thanks for answering.

Comment: That might be happening due to anti bot techniques used by the web site.  I can take a look if you can provide me the website.